# Transform array to associative Array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to transform

```
array(
   array(
      'id'  => 'id_3',
      'bla' => 'bla'
   )
)
```

into

```
array(
   'id_3' => array(
      'id'  => 'id_3',
      'bla' => 'bla'
   )
)
```

with `array_map()` or any other PHP function that is returning the array?

Comment: `$new = array('id_3'=>array_pop($original));` give the result you want from your example. But what you want to do is very very unclear. cant see any logic. And try some out by yourself and show code here.

Comment: `$array = array_combine(array_column($array, 'id'), $array);`

Comment: thx @MarkBaker thats exactly what i was looking for. Wonder why my question was downvoted. Can u post you solution as answer ?

Comment: I imagine it was downvoted because you didn't show much research or attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

this is a customize function, hope that will be useful and for you :

```
$input = array(
   array(
      'id'  => 'id_1',
      'ala' => 'ala'
   ),
   array(
      'id'  => 'id_2',
      'bla' => 'bla'
   ),
   array(
      'id'  => 'id_3',
      'cla' => 'cla'
   )
 );

function reorder($input){
    $result = array();
    foreach ($input as $key => $array) {
        $result[$array['id']] = $array;
    }
    return $result;
}

print_r($input);
print_r(reorder($input));
```

Thanks